# Use created attribute with javascript in select list

Tags: javascript

im trying to access an attribute that i created in a select list.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function updateUrl()
    {
        var newUrl=document.getElementById('test').car;
        alert(newUrl);
    }
</script>

<input type="text" id="test" car="red" value="create Attribute test" size="40"/> 
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="updateUrl();">
```

it keep giving me undefined. how do i get the string red from attribute car?

edit. i tried it with the select list it alerts null now

```
<select name= "test" id= "test" onChange= "updateUrl()">
     <option value="1" selected="selected" car="red">1</option> 
     <option value="2" car="blue" >2</option> 
     <option value="3" car="white" >3</option> 
     <option value="4" car="black" >4</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
var newUrl = document.getElementById('test').getAttribute('car');
```

**EDIT**

For the `<select>`, you have to look into the selected `<option>` element, not the `<select>` itself:

```
var select = document.getElementById('test');
select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('car');
```

Comment: @ajax333221 The question you linked to should be closed.