# get attribute value with javascript in select list

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use created attribute with javascript in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369241/use-created-attribute-with-javascript-in-select-list)

im trying to access an attribute that i created in a select list.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function updateUrl()
    {
        var newUrl = document.getElementById('test').getAttribute('car');
        alert(newUrl);
    }
</script>

<select name= "test" id= "test" onChange= "updateUrl()">
     <option value="1" selected="selected" car="red">1</option> 
     <option value="2" car="blue" >2</option> 
     <option value="3" car="white" >3</option> 
     <option value="4" car="black" >4</option>    
</select>
```

it keep giving me null. how do i get the value from attribute car?

Comment: Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You shouldn't be asking the same question twice, editing the other one was sufficient (makes the question show on the front page).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you meant get the value from the `car` attribute of the selected option:

```
//get the option's car attribute at selectedIndex
var car = document.getElementById('test').options[select.selectedIndex].car;
```

Comment: Using `.car` didn't work for me but changing that to `.getAttribute('car')` solved it for me. Thanks.

Comment: This is vague. What is select.selectedIndex? Also .car returned null in my case.

Answer (score 5):

This attribute isn't on the select. It's on the first option:

```
document.getElementById('test').options[0].getAttribute('car')
```

Comment: But this would work only for the first option, right?