# jQuery: accessing (multi) .attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I have a problem accessing the information of a (multi) `.attr(...)` 
I found  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369727/get-attribute-value-with-javascript-in-select-list) and tried to adapt it - but it does not work. I am missing something obvious here (new to js). Hope to find help here!

```js
var user_id = document.getElementById('myselect').options[select.selectedIndex].user_id;
var user_email = document.getElementById('myselect').options[select.selectedIndex].user_email;

document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 'User with ID' + user_id + " has email address " + user_email;
```

```html
<select id="myselect">
  <option user_email="test@test.de" user_id=1>Test 0</option>
  <option user_email="email@email.de" user_id=1>Test 1</option>
  <option user_email="whyso@serious.de" user_id=1>Test 3</option>
</select>

<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select.selectedIndex` doesn't exist in your example. This should work:

```
var select = document.getElementById('myselect');

var user_id = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('user_id');
var user_email = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('user_email');

document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 'User with ID' + user_id + " has email address " + user_email;
```

Comment: Obvious now! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var index = document.getElementById('myselect').selectedIndex;
var user_id = document.getElementById('myselect').options[index].getAttribute('user_id');
var user_email = document.getElementById('myselect').options[index].getAttribute('user_email');

document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 'User with ID' + user_id + " has email address " + user_email;
```